# Proper way to write my "index.php" file

Tags: php, indexing

I bought a book a month ago to start learning PHP, the problem about this book is that it doesn't tell you how to start writing your first pages, it only tells you what is a function, variables, classes, how they work and things like that.

I already finished the book, but as I said it doesn't tell you how to start, I tried to figure it out by myself, and my index.php file looks something like this:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myweb/lib/config.php);

session_start();
// checks if there is a valid session, if it is not valid, it will redirect to the login page
checkSession();

// if the session is valid it will display this file
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myweb/app/main.php);
```

It works fine, but sometimes it seems like it is slower as I keep adding functions, so I started wondering what is the proper way to write/build the index.php page? how do you write yours?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting checkSession from? The php equivalent is session_status. Other than that I'm not sure what you're asking - if you're asking for the most efficient design pattern then it's very much application specific. Code optimisation is a massive area and you've given us no indication of what these other functions do or how they do it. Can you clarify?

Comment: the checkSession function comes from the config file I include previously, what I want is an example or guidelines on how to build and include these files properly into the index file.